# TransformedField between "Cartesian" and "Polar"

Tags: fourier-analysis

When I do

```
    f[x_, y_] := Exp[-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]
    ft = FourierTransform[f[x, y], {x,y}, {u,v}, FourierParameters -> {0, 2*Pi} ]]
```

The result is
$$\frac{2 \pi }{\left(4 \pi ^2 \left(u^2+v^2\right)+1\right)^{3/2}}$$

If I do this in the Polar system and convert it back:

```
    f = Exp[-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]];
    fsp = Simplify[TransformedField["Cartesian" -> "Polar", f, {x, y} -> {r, \[Theta]}]]
    ft = Assuming[{r, \[Theta], \[Rho], \[CapitalTheta]} \[Element] 
    Reals  && \[Rho] >= 0,  FourierTransform[fsp, {r, \[Theta]}, {\[Rho], \[CapitalTheta]}, FourierParameters -> {0, 2*Pi} ]]
```

The result is
$$\frac{2 \delta (\Theta )}{4 \pi ^2 \rho ^2+1}$$

After I do

```
    Simplify[TransformedField[
  "Polar" -> 
   "Cartesian", %, {\[Rho], \[CapitalTheta]} -> {u, v}], \[Rho] >= 0]
```

I got
$$\frac{2 \delta \left(\tan ^{-1}(u,v)\right)}{4 \pi ^2 \left(u^2+v^2\right)+1}$$

So, I can not get the same result as when I do the Fourier Transform in the Cartesian system.

Can anyone tell me what's the problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you define `ft2[]`?

Comment: The first FFT gives you a function in the space (u,v) that is with base vectors: Exp[2Pi( x u+ y v]. The second FFT gives a function in a space with base vectors: Exp[2Pi(r ρ
+θ Θ]])] These are different spaces. Even if you express the second one in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Sorry for the mistake. It's 2D Fourier transform. I corrected it in the code.